# Linked List, delete tail function

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management, linked-list

I am trying to build a head delete and tail delete function for Linked Lists.

I have succeeded in head delete, but my tail delete function does not actually delete the tail.

First, how my Linked List is created:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

} node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;

} LinkedList;

node *createNode(int data)
{
    node *new_node;

    if ((new_node = malloc(sizeof(node))) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

LinkedList *createLinkedList(void)
{
    LinkedList *LL;

    if ((LL = calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList))) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return LL;
}

void tailInsert(LinkedList *LL, int data)
{

    if (LL == NULL)
        return;

    if (LL->tail == NULL)
    {
        LL->head = LL->tail = createNode(data);
        return;
    }

    LL->tail->next = createNode(data);
    LL->tail = LL->tail->next;

}
```

These are the two functions:

This one does not work:

```
int tail_Delete(LinkedList *list)
{
    int retval;
    node *temp;

    if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL)
        return EMPTY_LIST_ERR;

    // if only one node
    if (list->head->next == NULL)
    {
        retval = list->head->data;
        free(list->head);
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;
        return retval;
    }

    // make temp the node before the tail
    for (temp = list->head; temp->next != list->tail; temp = temp->next)
        ;

    retval = list->tail->data;

    free(list->tail);

    list->tail = temp;

    return retval;
}
```

This one does work:

```
int head_delete(LinkedList *list)
{
    int retval;
    node *temp;

    if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL)
        return EMPTY_LIST_ERR;

    retval = list->head->data;

    temp = list->head->next;

    free (list->head);

    list->head = temp;

    if (list->head == NULL)
        list->tail = NULL;

    return retval;
}
```

Print function and main:

```
void print_Linked_list(LinkedList *LL)
{
    node *temp;

    if (LL == NULL || LL->head == NULL)
        return;

    for (temp = LL->head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        printf("%d%c", temp->data, (temp->next == NULL) ? '\n' : ' ');

}

int main(void)
{
    LinkedList *LL;
    int val;

    LL = createLinkedList();

    tailInsert(LL, 1);
    tailInsert(LL, 2);
    tailInsert(LL, 3);

    print_Linked_list(LL);

    val = tail_Delete(LL);
    //val = head_delete(LL);

    printf("%d\n", val);

    print_Linked_list(LL);

    return 0;
}
```

Output for head_delete:

```
1 2 3
Deleted node: 1
2 3
```

Output for tail_delete:

```
1 2 3
Deleted node: 3
1 2 3
```

It may be a simple mistake, but they seem to be practically equivalent functions.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tail delete needs to be managed from the node *before* the tail.  If you don't have a back pointer in the list (doubly linked), then you'll need to walk forward to the tail.

Untested, tail delete (with no back pointer) should look like this.

```
LinkedList *node = list->head;
LinkedList *next = node->next;

while(next != list->tail) {  // walk to the end
    node = next;
    next = node->next;
}
// now node is the node before the tail and next is the tail
int retval = next->data;
free(next);
// this is why we needed to walk here
node->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign 0 to `temp->next` pointer when `for` loop was executed. By this you indicate that this element is last one.

```
for (temp = list->head; temp->next != list->tail; temp = temp->next)
    ;

temp->next = 0; // <---

retval = list->tail->data;
```

Comment: Note that `0` is not the `NULL` pointer. So it should be `temp->next = NULL;` instead. Because otherwise it's not possible to tell form the code you posted whether `next` is a pointer or an integer.